# Should I query my Firebase database directly, or use Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I am  still new to solo-writing a back-end to my app so I have some concerns,

the concern I am asking about here is a security concern about sharing my database structur in the client app,

As it is known all code that is written on client side is "not safe from interested clients",

I read this [medium post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c) by Doug Stevenson from the firebase team,

What I am looking for exactly is an answer to the title of my question (which is the same title as the post on medium):

> Should I query my Firebase database directly, or use Cloud Functions?

but I didn't really get an answer as he said that it depends on the situation and requirements of my app,

So can anyone tell me if it is ok,from a security perspective, to do direct queries on the client side that expose the structure of data in my database (firestore), or should I use instead only cloud functions for this?

notes:

1. I am aware that real-time data can only be achieved using client-sdks and thus I should give up that feature if I don't want to share my database structure in the client app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing direct client access is as safe as you choose to make it.

There's nothing about the **structure** of data that's not secure.  Your implementation lacks security only if users are able to do things that you didn't intend for them to do.  That's entirely up to you to implement with security rules.  If your rules accurately express what users should and should not be able to do, you will have no problem.  If you are unable to use security rules to meet your needs, then you should force access through a backend.

Comment: So having direct queries in my client app along with having robust security rules is not a bad developer practice? (this should've been last line in my question)

Comment: This is exactly what the Firebase documentation is recommending to you.

Comment: I know I marked this answer as true, but I am facing a problem here,now that cloud functions are going to be on paid plan,I can't use them anymore, and I am developing an game that saves its state on firestore, so now if I want to put the backend logic (writes to the backend) on the client app, I can't use security rules to protect my database because the rules are so complex and depend on the state of the game, previously I would do that using cloud functons,but now I can't use them as I said bcz I don't have blaze plan

Comment: so does it mean now that firestore is not right place as my backend? and I should roll out my own server? Sorry for late comment but this came out now

Comment: What you're asking now is a matter of opinion.  Questions asking opinions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  I suggest posting to a discussion group that allows for general conversation.

Comment: Keep in mind, the Blaze plan only requires that you *have* a credit card. unless you're pushing some serious numbers, you're unlikely to cross the free-tier threshold, and even if you did, the costs associated with such a thing are likely to be negligible.